# How to handle Incorrect JSON syntax in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

I have a spring MVC Project, wherein I need to handle incorrect JSON syntax.
Spring MVC throws an error as text/html, which looks like:

Apache Tomcat/7.0.47 - Error report

## HTTP Status 400 -

**type** Status report

**message**

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

#### Apache Tomcat/7.0.47

However I want to throw my own exception in JSON format.
Is there any way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this as well, here's what I found to fix it:

The [Spring MVC docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestbody) reference `HttpMessageConverter` as responsible for converting a `@ResponseBody`. For JSON, you're likely using a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`, which when attempting to convert a message can throw a [`HttpMessageNotReadableException`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/HttpMessageNotReadableException.html).

If you have some form of exception handler for that, you can intercept the 400 response.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug to see which Exception is actually thrown (might be a `TypeMismatchException` or something like that). Then, you can specify an error handler in your controller like

```
@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
public String handleTypeMismatchException(TypeMismatchException ex) {

}
```

Now, in this controller method you can do whatever you want, like passing it the model, request, response etc. You can send to a view, redirect or in your case use a `ResponseBody` or however else you would like to serve your JSON error.